# AuthComponent isAuthorized and redirect

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm  trying to implement a basic role based authorization mechanism in CakePHP using the `AuthComponent` and *controller authorization* while handling authorization logic in the `isAuthorized()` function in my controllers. So far so good.

What I do want is to stop the redirects if a user is already logged in.

For instance: Logged in User tries to access */posts/edit/2* . The user is not authorized to edit this post since he is not the owner. How do I stop CakePHP from automatically redirecting to the login page. I just want to throw a *401* or *403* for that matter at the user. (Although I think *401* is more appropriate). I could do a `redirect()` or throw a `UnauthorizedException` in the `isAuthorized()` function. But I think this is not a clean way to handle this. And it will also break my `parent::isAuthorized();` function.

I hope anyone has handled this situation before and can tell me how to implement this in a nice and clean way.

Comment: Before proceeding the action, just check the login-in user with the owner of that user. If doesn't match just redirect to error page.